# Problem with probabilities of functions of continuous random vector

Tags: random-variable, continuous-data, function

I have problems with a true or false exercise: if the joint pdf of the continuous random vector $(X,Y)$ is
$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}2x,& 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le 1,\\
0,& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}, $$
then $P\!\left(X^2 < Y < 2X\right)=5/12.$

I´m not sure if I have to find the probabilities separately or compute a complete integral with the joint pdf of two different functions, $U=\left(X^2,Y\right)$ and $V=(2X,Y),$ which I'm not sure how to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [draw the region carefully](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=plot%20Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%3Cy%3C2x%20on%200%3C%3Dx%3C%3D1%5C%2844%29%200%3C%3Dy%3C%3D1) in the square $[0,1]\times[0,1],$ you will see that setting up the required integral is a bit easier if you integrate first with respect to $x,$ viewing $x=g(y)$ on the boundaries of the region. In fact, the required integral is
\begin{align*}
P\!\left(X^2<Y<2X\right)
&=\int_0^1\int_{y/2}^\sqrt{y}2x\,dx\,dy.
\end{align*}
I'll leave it to you to work out that this does, in fact, equal $5/12.$

The alternative would be the somewhat more laborious, but still correct, version:
$$P\!\left(X^2<Y<2X\right)=
\int_0^{1/2}\int_{x^2}^{2x}2x\,dy\,dx
+\int_{1/2}^1\int_{x^2}^12x\,dy\,dy.$$
This also works out to $5/12.$